# Cosmos DB ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync is not returning the response

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying the call the JavaScript SP in my Document DB (Cosmos DB), though my intended records are getting updated in Document DB, I am not getting the response back to the caller.

Control is not coming back to the caller and there is no exception as well.

```cs
var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>(sp.SelfLink, new RequestOptions
                {
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey),
                    AccessCondition = new AccessCondition()
                    {
                        Type = AccessConditionType.IfMatch
                    }

                }, parameters);
```

Comment: Hi, any progress now?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
 private List<Dictionary<string, object>> _items { get; } = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        private readonly DocumentClient _client;
        private readonly Uri _sprocLink;

        public CosmosDBStreamPersisterBatch(DocumentClient client, Uri sprocLink)
        {
            _client = client;
            _sprocLink = sprocLink;
        }

        public async Task<StoredLatency> Commit()
        {
            var partitionKey = _items.First()[nameof(StreamEntityBase.PartitionKey)];

            var response = await _client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(_sprocLink, 
                new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(partitionKey) }, 
                new { docs = _items });
            return new StoredLatency() { NumItems = _items.Count, Time = StreamEntityPersisterPartition.GetStoredLatency(_items) };
        }

        public void AddItem(Dictionary<string, object> item)
        {
            _items.Add(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my working code:

```
private static readonly string endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
private static readonly string authorizationKey = "***";
private static readonly string databaseId = "db";
private static readonly string collectionId = "part";

private static DocumentClient client;

public static void QueryTestAsync()

        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);

            var requestOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("white") };

            StoredProcedureResponse<string> sprocResponse = client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>("dbs/db/colls/part/sprocs/1/", requestOptions).Result;

            Console.WriteLine("Execute Output: {0}", sprocResponse.Response);
        }
```